# Using XamlRenderingBackgroundTask in C#-BackgroundTask

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I want to render a bitmap in an Universal App for Windows (Phone) 8.1 in a background task in order to update my Live Tile.
The only way I suppose this is possible is RenderTargetBitmap. Unfortunately the `RenderAsync()` method results in an **ArgumentException** in my code.

I downloaded [an example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Updating-a-tile-from-a-e0e492df) below in which the background task is implemented in C++. It uses the XamlRenderingBackgroundTask-class and the **RenderAsync()** method works.

```
public ref class AppTileUpdater sealed : XamlRenderingBackgroundTask
```

Unfortunately I didn't find a way yet to use this class in my C#-Project. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Its same as C++, Look for samples of RenderTargetBitmap in C# and use that in override method of OnRun() in your AppTileUpdater class

Note: Recommended approach is to use C++ due to memory limitation on low end devices

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer and code snippet on the MSDN forum.  It's the C# version of the C++ example.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43295c90-43e8-4b08-8a25-958a1c3d0a0b/explanation-on-windowsuixamlmediaxamlrenderingbackgroundtask?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK